# How to "remove software from Launchpad PPA" in order to do-release-upgrade?

Tags: 16.04, apt, ppa, launchpad, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 16 LTS with a command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

but it failes with

```
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This was likely caused by:
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and
try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.If
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade.
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.
```

What she wants and how to satisfy her? I tried to remove all packages from `launchpad.net` but it didn't help.

Comment: Try to also [remove the PPAs themselves](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/12/how-to-remove-ppa-ubuntu) and not only the program packages, that you installed from there: So first remove those program packages, then remove the PPAs.

Comment: I don't understand, what it means. Suppose my list file has a line `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main`. How to convert it to `ppa:dhor/myway`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Referring to your comment about `ppa:dhor/myway`

The following command line can be used to remove the PPA (the option `-r` causes removal),

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:dhor/myway
sudo apt-get update
```

### Your comment about `.../webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
```

corresponds to (can be removed with)

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Please notice that [this PPA is discontinued](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java).

Comment: What is `ppa:dhor/myway`?

Comment: If you have it, I would guess that you know what it is. I have not used it, but you can see [this link](https://launchpad.net/~dhor/+archive/ubuntu/myway)

Comment: I guess I don't have it. How to know these names for my PPAs?

Comment: Can you see in the output of `sudo apt update`, if there is any [other] PPA?

Comment: Sorry thank you very much!

Comment: @Dims, You are welcome and good luck with your upgrade from 16.04 LTS :-)